# Use options in Package

Tags: beamer, fonts, fontsize, sourcesanspro

For the font Source Sans Pro I want to use the semibold font instead of bold. The [documentation](https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/fonts/sourcesanspro/doc/sourcesanspro.pdf) indicates I should enable the option "semibold", but I do not know how to enable it. Here is my attempt which does not work

```
\setsansfont{Source Sans Pro Light}
\setmonofont{Source Sans Pro Light}
  
\setbeamerfont{title}{series= \semibold,parent=structure}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\semibold,parent=structure}
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: HI on TeX ! Please provide us a MWE !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `semibold` is an option of the package. Using `\setsansfont` loads the font directly instead of via the package.

The following loads the `sourcesanspro` package with the `semibold` option (which makes bold semibold), and sets the title/frametitle font series to bold:

```latex
\usepackage[semibold]{sourcesanspro}
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries,parent=structure}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries,parent=structure}
```

Of course, it is also possible to use the semibold variant only in the titles:

```latex
\usepackage{sourcesanspro}
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries,family=\sourcesansprolight,parent=structure}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries,family=\sourcesansprolight,parent=structure}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. It solves the problem perfectly